# C# - Downloading website with webcrawler for ajax page

Tags: c#, ajax, web-crawler

I've written a simple Web crawler project in c# (using Microsoft WebCrawler) that download the content of a specific site.

I've registered to the event for `DocumentCompleted` and waiting for the `ReadyState` of the page to be Complete.

When i'm navigating to the page using any browser the site works perfectly fine.
When I'm trying to do the the same throughout my code the ajax part of the page is not loading correctly.

As **Marcom** suggested I looked at the response with fiddler, both from my web crawler and from a web browser. When my web crawler navigates to the web page he receives false on one of the params in contrary of the web page.

Any lead?

Comment: `Ajax page` doesn't say very much. How is the page loaded normally? through a javascript? It will complicate things a lot.

Comment: In 'Ajax page' i wanted to say that the page consist of 2 parts - the first is a normal html part and the second is loaded after the page is done loading and sent to the client...

Answer (score 1):

you will probably have to simulate the requests done by ajax to download the rest of the data.

Use a tool like fiddler to see what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a logic reason why the page is sometimes loading the Ajax part and sometimes not?

Comment: you have to be more specific, i cant make blind guesses :)

Comment: The ajax part of the page sometimes successfully loading and sometimes not. Is there a reason why this will happen? 
In addition, should I change the headers of the webcrawler to behave like i'm not a webcrawler?